# undirected graph: generalized connected components

Tags: boost-graph

I need to split an undirected graph (with unit node weight everywhere, but that might not be relevant) into (A) connected components (separated by 0 edges), but also components connected by (B) only 1, only 2 (and so on) edges.

I've been using `boost::graph::connected_components` for (A) and I am considering how to tackle (B). My initial idea is to use results from (A) and then, for each connected component, recursively isolate 1-connected components by using Stoer-Wagner min=cut (`boost::graph::stoer_wagner_min_cut`) as long as there is a cut with unit cost (1 edge).

It might be that there is a specific name for this task (which I don't know) or that BGL or some other library already provides aan algorithm for solving this.

Thanks for pointers/suggestions.